# Display Detail Component Using React Router

Tags: reactjs

I want to display a CourseDetail component when user clicks a link using react router.
But when I add router to index.js, the main page displays blank. How do I add router correctly? Thanks.
Below index.js works when no router for CourseDetail.js component

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
 </BrowserRouter>,
 document.getElementById("root")
 );
```

Below code displays blank after adding router for CourseDetail.js
`

```
 ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path='/course/:CLASSNBR' component={CourseDetail} />      
      <Route  path="/" exact component={App} />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `react-router v5` you need to wrap your routes within `<Switch></Switch>`. If you are using `react-router v6`, you need to wrap your routes within `<Routes></Routes>`.

Comment: I am using "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0".  I wrapped Route with Routes but it still does not display anything. By the way, my App.js populates URL parameters using useEffect(() => {
    const currentParams = Object.fromEntries([...searchParams]);  Will this stop the react router from displaying contents?

Comment: Post all the detailed code of your App.js, if you want to change route you need to use `useNavigate()` hook.

Comment: You are right. It works after I move the the code to App.js instead of index.js. But the link does not take user to CourseDetail.js component. It opens URL like localhost:http://localhost:3004/course/CLASSNBRXXX. My code is like this:  <Routes>
        <Route path="/course/:CLASSNBR" Component={CourseDetail} />
        <Route exact path="/" Component={App} />
      </Routes>
   <Link to={{ pathname: "/course/" + course.CLASSNBR }}>
                View More
              </Link>

Comment: Please edit your original question with additional code and info.

Comment: I figured it out. The syntax is different in react router v6. I have to use <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/course/:CLASSNBR" element={<CourseDetail />} />
      <Route exact path="/" element={<App />} />
    </Routes>    Note: element instead of component.  {<CourseDetail />} instead of {CourseDetails} .  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, and you don't need to set "exact" anymore.